# Getting the data of a form containing a file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following html form:

```
<form method="post" class="treeWidgetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Photo :</label> <br/>
                                    <input type="file" name="imgFile">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Firstname :</label> <br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="treeWidgetInput"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Lastname :</label> <br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="treeWidgetInput"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Gender :</label> <br/>
                                    <label class="treeWidgetRadio"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="treeWidgetRadio"><input type="radio" name="gender"
                                                                          value="female">Female
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Birth date :</label> <br/>
                                    <input id="birthdate" type="text" name="birthdate" class="treeWidgetInput"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Death date :</label> <br/>
                                    <input id="deathdate" type="text" name="deathdate" class="treeWidgetInput"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Nationality :</label> <br/>
                                    <select name="nationality" class="treeWidgetInput"></select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <label>Country :</label> <br/>
                                    <select name="country" class="treeWidgetInput"></select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row spaced">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default treeWidgetFormBtn"
                                                data-operation="cancelPerson">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary treeWidgetFormBtn"
                                                data-operation="savePerson">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I need to get the data contained in this form so I could send it via an AJAX request to server. I wrote the following javascript function that recieves a form element as parameter:

```
FormUtils.getFormData = function(form) {
  var data = {};
  $(form).serializeArray().
      map(function (x) {
         data[x.name] = x.value;
      });
  return data;
};
```

[image]

It works for all form fields except the 'file' input.It can't get the file object that I try to pass in the input named 'imgFile' of type 'file'. I did some search and stumbled on FormData function. I rewrote the function like this:

```
FormUtils.getFormData = function(form) {
    var data = new FormData($(form)[0]);
    return data;
};
```

The FormData function returns me an empty object. Here are some Chrome debugging screenshots:

[image: Debugging]
[image]

I don't understand why FormData creates an empty object. I can see from debugger that the 'form' object I pass to the function is a form element. How should I create my data object so I could send it like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: dataObj,
        type: "PUT",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try FileReader API something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>        
  function handleFileSelect()
  {               
    if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
      alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
      return;
    }   

    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    if (!input) {
      alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");               
    }
    else {
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      //fr.readAsText(file);
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  function receivedText() {           
    //result = fr.result;
               document.getElementById('editor').appendChild(document.createTextNode(fr.result))
  }           

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="fileinput"/>
<input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='handleFileSelect();'>
<div id="editor"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find get some knowledge here:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=59bT9DGXOkX

Comment: This works indeed. However, it is similar to an asynchronous call. I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with FormData function. From examples I've seen, FormData seemed like the most simple one.